# export google chart to pdf in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I'm trying to export image from google chart to pdf in Redmine and i didn't know how to proceed. i tried the last version of redmine but it doesn't work. I don't want to use Wkhtmltopdf and wicked_pdf.

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=x%3D\fr{-b\pm\sq{b^2-4ac}}{2a}&chco=000000&chf=bg%2Cs%2CFFFFFF00

Comment: Here is a link that could help you https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing

Comment: This one i use JS but in my case i should use these gems: rfpdf or rbpdf